# What will be the buoyant force on an object in an accelerating container?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, buoyancy, fluid-statics

Our teacher taught us it is vρ(g+a) when accelerating upward. But I can't understand the reason for it. Isn't it vρg as buoyant force is equal to the weight of displaced fluid. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it like this: By accelerating upwards with an acceleration $a$, you introduce an inertial force in the direction of $g$. This leads to an effective increase of the specific weight of the water: $\rho g\rightarrow \rho(g+a)$ So the buoyant force is still equal to the weight of the displaced fluid.

Comment: isn't the direction of g downward?

Comment: Yes. And if you accelerate a water container upwards, you have to overcome the inertia of the water. This is why you obtain a downward force even though the container moves upwards.
It is like in a car that accelerates quickly. You are pressed into your seat despite the fact that the car moves in the opposite direction.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. What did you mean by introducing an inertial force in the direction of g. Though acceleration is upwards? I'm still learning fluid dynamics.

Comment: Imagine you are sitting in a car. The car accelerates really quickly. As a consequence, you are pressed into the seat, i.e. there is a net force pressing you into your seat. This force occurs due to inertia.

If you transfer this everyday example to the water container: The container is the car and you represent the water. By accelerating the container, the water is pressed into the bottom of the container.

In both cases, the force which presses you/water into the car seat/container, is in opposite direction to the acceleration, e.g. you are pressed backwards but the car moves forward.

Answer (score 0):

Buoyancy comes from the difference in pressure on an object. For simplicity, first consider a cube of side L in non-moving fluid.  The pressure at the bottom is $gL\rho$ more than at the top, so the net upward force is $gL{\rho}L^2$ or $gL^3\rho$, the weight of the displaced fluid.

Now consider your up-going case. If that cube was fluid, it would also need to have enough net pressure to accelerate with the container (just like the fluid arranges itself to stay in place in the stationary case, it does the same for the accelerating case).  That’s a total force of $a$ time the mass or $aL^3\rho$.

So the total force, which we’ll know as the buoyancy force, is $(g+a)L^3\rho$.